# Arabic letters shown disconnected in Flash

Tags: flash, arabic

I am having this issue where Arabic letters are shown disjoint in any component (e.g. Label or TextInput) in Flash. Any suggestions?

Comment: Has the text direction been set to right to left (not a full answer because I'm not a flash developer, but this is often the first thing that breaks the start/middle/end glyph selection in Arabic fonts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash did not have a good text engine for right-to-left languages.
It has one starting with version 10, but the authoring tools did not catch up yet.

You can use the next text engine by taking the helper library they published (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/), or by using the new Spark components in Flex 4, which use the new text engine by default.

Answer (score 2):

These blog posts might be of help:

- [How to write arabic in Flash](http://joeabiraad.com/design/how-to-write-arabic-in-flash-8)
- [Arabic Text in Flash CS3](http://blog.flavert.com/2008/02/15/arabic-text-in-flash-cs3/)

Answer (score 0):

Flash CS5 has the ability now to deal with arabic letter from right to left with connecting letter 
just look for the locale select menu in the text menu

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee-4b0db644124bbdb363d-8000.html
and look for The ability to create right-to-left text for Arabic and Hebrew scripts.

[Flash CS5 character styles](http://www.flashconf.com/flash-cs5/flash-cs5-character-styles/)

its working very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Embedding font and Device Font for Anti-Aliasing in Flash CS5, worked for me