# Reversed and separated Farsi/Arabic characters in adobe Flash on Ubuntu 64 Bit

Tags: linux, flash, ubuntu, adobe, arabic

If there is any Farsi characters in Adobe flashes on websites; they show reversed and separated such as bellow screenshot that takes from facebook video player in firefox :

[alt text http://i.imagehost.org/0476/Screenshot.png](http://i.imagehost.org/0476/Screenshot.png)

found something that shows this problem is from flash text engine ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579410/arabic-letters-shown-disconnected-in-flash/1713696#1713696)).
but Adobe has just presented reformed [**text layout framework**](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/) for flex and flash 10 that is for developer side not for us as an end-user.

What could we do as end-users to correct this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your screenshot is broken.